# R package from local drive

Tags: r

I don't have access to internet. Hence, i downloaded sqldf package from other system and then transfer it to this system.

The sqldf_0.4-10.tar file is saved in "C:\Users\Riya\Documents\R" and also saved binary file in the same folder. I want to install the package with dependencies as well. When i am installing the package using "Install Package from local zip file" under "Packages" dropwdown. It is not installing dependencies. I googled solutions and found :

```
tools::write_PACKAGES("C:/Users/Riya/Documents/R/")
```

After that,

```
install.packages("sqldf", repos="file://C:/Users/Riya/Documents/R/")
```

It is giving me an error -

```
source repository is unavailable to check versions 
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : cannot open the connection 
In addition: Warning message: 
In read.dcf(file = tmpf) : 
cannot open compressed file '//C:/Users/Riya/Documents/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'>
```

It's a window system. 
Note : `tools::write_PACKAGES()` creates 2 files. I also deleted "PACKAGES.gz" file as per the solution mentioned in a forum.

Comment: Download the `sqldf_0.4-10.zip` file from CRAN, be sure that R is on your PATH and from the Windows CMD line (not within R) issue the command:  `R CMD INSTALL sqldf_0.4-10.zip`   Be sure you have installed its dependencies (gsubfn, proto, RSQLite and DBI) first.

Answer (score 4):

From the R console you can go with:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Riya/Documents/R/sqldf_0.4-10.tar", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

You can also install from OS command line, using R CMD INSTALL as G. Grothendieck wrote in the comment.

Comment: If the package has compiled code there need to be a proper copy of RTools installed. Fortunately `help(pac=sqldf)` shows that not to be the case here. But I suppose G.Gothendieck would have mentioned that since he's the supervisor/maintainer of that excellent Google SoC project.

Comment: Thanks! What i understand - I need to install dependencies before installing the desired package. There is no way out to install only the required package, not dependencies as some packages like ggplot have many dependencies. Installing each dependency is a tedious preocess. Last Question - What's the difference between "Package Source" and " Windows Binaries" ?

Comment: @Riya binaries is the source code compiled under particular OS, source is universal for all OSes. It is better to deal with sources than binaries as binaries may be compiled only for particular architecture x64/x86, etc. Compiling from source on windows requires Rtools as mentioned by BondedDust.

Comment: If you install the binary (rather than the source) then you don't need Rtools even if the package uses compiled code.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Last question - Do i need to install all the pakages that are mentioned against "Import" and "Depend" sections in the desired package?I have installed the desired package before installing dependencies. Should i remove the desired package (from window library) and then install their dependencies first?

Answer (score -1):

Installing multiple packages from local zip files in R [ Windows 7 32 bit and RGui(32bit) i386 3.3.0  ]

*i am not use to in R, even Stack.

In simple way we do ---

1. Download the ZIP file of the package,save it to local drive of your computer.
2. Run following R commands

   ```
   install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)
   ```

   - The `file.choose()` command will show a window allowing you to choose the `.zip` file or the `tar.gz` file where you downloaded it.

Now we try to installing multiple packages form local drive ---

1. Download the ZIP file of the package,save it to local drive of your computer.
2. Open RGui i386 3.3.0.
3. In R Console run following commands -

   ```
   result <- array(list.files(path = "D:/Backup/R tutorial/downloaded_packages", pattern = "*.zip", all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE))
   ```

   - The `result` store the the list of zip files name in array until the value replace by any way or close the RGui (work space).
   - The `path = "..."` replace your own drive path.
   - The `pattern = "..."` may replace `"tar.gz"` but i did not test it yet.
4. Now run the loop to install all zip files:

   ```
   for(i in 1:length(result)) {
     x <- paste("D:/Backup/R tutorial/downloaded_packages/",result[i], sep="", collapse = NULL)
     print(i)
     print(result[i])
     install.packages(x, repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
     # readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
   }
   ```

   - In `x` we store the file name, `paste` help me to do that.
   - `install.packages(x, repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")` installing the zip file(s) one by one.
   - The `readline` take input from a user to continue the loop. Here i comment it by `#`
5. Normal loop execution -

   ```
   [1] 7402   
   [1] "RKEELdata_1.0.3.zip"
   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Amitava Kar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   ```
6. Common Error and exit loop -

   ```
   [1] 7403
   [1] "RKEELjars_1.0.15.zip"
   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Amitava Kar/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
     cannot open the connection
   In addition: Warning messages:
   1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
   2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
     cannot open compressed file 'RKEELjars/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
   ```

   - This error show when the zip file is corrupt or not readable.
   - The `print(i)` show the number of array read e.g.  `[1] 7403`
   - The `print(result[i])` show the zip file  e.g.  `[1] "RKEELjars_1.0.15.zip"`
   - now manually download and replace the zip file and change in loop
     `for(i in 1:length(result))` by `for(i in 7403:length(result))` and re run the 
     program again e.g.

     ```
     for(i in 7403:length(result)) {
     x <- paste("D:/Backup/R tutorial/downloaded_packages/",result[i], sep="", collapse = NULL)
     print(i)
     print(result[i])
     install.packages(x, repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
     # readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
     }
     ```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to say with this answer? It is a lot of text and it is not clear to me if you answer a question or ask a new one.

Comment: Hi Paul,
sorry, it's my bad.
i just try to ans to "Installing multiple packages from a local zip files in R". when we have (more than one) multiple packages (*.zip files), already downloaded into local drive.

Comment: I tried cleaning up the formatting a bit, that also made it very hard to read.